# Open file picker for specific file extension

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I have `Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)`, I need it to be able open custom file extension, simply say it haven't mime-type to pass to `setType()` to filter files (as I suppose there is some way to bind extension with mime-type). Please help!

Comment: "I have Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)" -- with reference to your question title, this is not a file picker. "I need it to be able open custom file extension" -- use `*/*` as the MIME type in your `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent`. Bear in mind that there is no requirement for the content that the user picks to *have* a file extension, and of course there is no requirement that a file extension be valid anyway.

Comment: @CommonsWare I want to understand how system detects that some file matches e.g. "image/*", if file itself doesn't carry information about that.

Comment: Often, the MIME type came from someplace else. For example, `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62362740/open-file-picker-for-specific-file-extension` is the URL for this Web page. It does not have any file extension, let alone `.html`. The Web browser knows the MIME type because the Web server told it what the MIME type was in the HTTP response.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I understand that, how to tell to system file picker (and other file browsers) that the file is actually of some specific mime-type.

Comment: You can't. Custom file extensions have never been well-supported in Android.